# Is it posible to export the Analysis and Comments from TFS Work Items to Jira

Tags: tfs, jira

I'm trying to import some work items from TFS2013 to Jira. Jira seems to only support importing from CSV in this scenario.

I've connected Excel up to TFS and run a query to get all the data items for the work items I need, but the Choose columns dialogue in Excel is not giving me the option to export the Analysis and Comments section of the work items.

I'd be happy to simply have all the history items concatenated together into one big text field. I don't really need them to be separate items in Jira's history tough that would be nice if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that the Excel provider is not able to export comments. But you can try https://tfsworkitemsexporter.codeplex.com/ This tool can export comments.

For a full replication JIRA <-> TFS have a look at https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.spartez.jira.plugins.bork.tfs4jira/cloud/overview